# Adding wireframe to RegionPlot3D

Tags: visualization

I'm looking to make my 3D region plots sharper by adding wireframes -- mark sharp angles with black (ie, all areas where constraints intersect)

An example: the first plot already comes with a wireframe (4 black circles), whereas the second plot looks softer. It's missing 4 black vertical segments and 2 curvy segments. Any tips?

```
plot1 = RegionPlot3D[{0.9 < x^2 + y^2 < 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
   1}, {z, 0, .1}, Axes -> False, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 75, 
  Boxed -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]

plot2 = RegionPlot3D[{0.9 <= x + y <= 1 && -1 <= x - y <= 1 && 
    0 <= z <= 2/(\[Pi] Sqrt[(1 + x - y) (1 - x + y)])}, {x, -1, 
   1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 3}, Mesh -> False, BoundaryStyle -> Black, 
  PlotPoints -> 175, Axes -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there no general way.

```
Plot3D[{2/(π Sqrt[(1 + x - y) (1 - x + y)]), 0}, {x, -1, 
  1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, 0.9 <= x + y <= 1 && -1 <= x - y <= 1], 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 3}}, Filling -> 0, 
 FillingStyle -> Yellow, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, `Plot3D` + `RenderingOptions->{"3DRenderingMethod"->"BSPTree"}]` seems to give the desired result ([post](https://machine-learning-etc.ghost.io/p/765acb0d-0985-4f91-8db5-d9457f11425f/))